# MySql databases corrupted after upgrade?

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu

I have been dealing with this issue for a while now. For some reason, when i went to run a Ubuntu upgrade, MySql-server upgrade failed. This was on about 8/10. This had happened before due to a "DATADIR" link (won't go into detail on that just now). I went through hell trying to get the package to upgrade and eventually got the package to upgrade by creating a new MySql database structure (after moving mine somewhere else). Once I did that (with some steps involved) the package upgrade completed.

Then, when I tried to replace the "new" databases with my old onse, it wouldn't start the service. I came to find out that the "Mmysql" (system) database folder was just completely gone.

So, I took the "new" database and overlayed it on my "old" database files. This got me in! Of course, old users, and anything else in the system database, was gone. So I started to rebuild them.

The problem occurred when i tried to go into *some* old databases. About half of them report that the table does not exist when trying to load them. Mostly, it is all of the tables in particular database, but there are a few databases where some tables "don't exist" and others do.

The thing is that the tables *do* exist. I believe they are simply corrupt.

So, I'm really trying here, but I can't seem to figure out how to get all of the tables to load. I have a backup from the 13th, presumably after the upgrade failed but before I really started messing with things. I'm going to try to use that, but if anyone knows how/why some tables are corrupted all of a sudden and why others are not and *especially* if someone knows how to fix this, that would be absolutely wonderful.

Unfortunately, my regular backups haven't been working for months, and the latest backup I currently have access to is 2 years old. Quite a bit has changed in the database since then, but as a last ditch effort, I may try to import that data and use "mysql_upgrade" to restore this, then overlay any new databases I have created since then into the directory structure and see if they import that way.

Thanks for any suggestions you may offer.

--mobrien

Comment: "Something" went wrong isn't really helpful. Please add the (error) messages you got/get when starting your server (with your files from 13th, not with the ones you messed with, it's kinda expected that it won't work when you randomly replace or add files), and maybe your config files. All you (would) have to do is a clean install, remove and replace EVERYTHING in `/var/lib/mysql/` with your original data from your backup and run an `mysql_upgrade`, assuming your backup isn't corrupt (e.g. if you just copied the files while the server was running or just copied some data).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was due to a permissions issue that had some files locked and when I fixed the perm issue, the tables that were accessible were corrupted. I restored the same backup again and this time it worked. The only folder that was missing was the "mysql" folder, and for that I recreated a new one, then patched it in, then created new user permissions for the existing tables. This was working, but then I ran into another issue, so I will open a new questions for that. This has been a nightmare and the moral of the story is: keep better backups and test them!

Comment: I spent 3 hours trying to restore a backup from the data folder to no avail. As a last resort I copied over the /var/lib/mysql/mysql folder to the corrupted install and was able to do a mysqldump and then restore it to a proper working server.